# How to check whether SLA rule have executed or not pega, using pega system variable?

Tags: pega

I have wriiten sla rule in my project and i want to check whether that rule have executed or not using pega system variable.

Comment: Your work object's `pxUpdateOperator` property will have value as `System` once `SLA` has executed. Is that enough?

Comment: yes that's enough..thank you

Comment: could you please accept the answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work object's `pxUpdateOperator` property will have value as `System` once `SLA` has executed.